# Questions regarding Rigify feature sets for eyes and other things

Tags: rigify

I am creating a somewhat complex rig since quite some time and I ran into some questions:

does anybody know if it is possible to separate the eye part of the Rigify human meta rig for a custom face rig? I am talking about this part (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU8ar.jpg). I can build it myself but I am lazy and I like these widgets and how they function. Rigify doesn't have this as a sample it seems and just separating the eye parts or deleting everything else does nothing. Or maybe there is a feature set that contains an eye rig? The ones I know of do not have that.

Is it possible to somehow get the widgets Rigify uses for its meta rigs that aren't available in the default widgets? Maybe some Widget expansion addon or something? Yes, I could also just copy them, but that seems like a hassle if I generate the rig new a lot due to small changes ...

Is it somehow possible to keep custom added constraints on samples "intact" when generating the rig? For example, if I use an aim constraint on the head deform bone from a head sample to aim on a custom control bone it will just do nothing because generating the rig will create a new control bone for the deform bone and thus the custom constraint gets "overwritten". Creating constraints anew after every time I generate the rig is getting tiresome.

Is it possible to add custom rig "Main Properties" (you know, like Neck Follow, IK/FK Switch and such) without coding?

Thanks.

Edit: I seem to like to ask if something is possible. :D

Comment: CG Dive have done a complete video series about Rigify [here](https://cgdive.com/rigify-tutorial-series-intro/) which you might find useful.

Comment: Yeah, I actually learned rigging through his rigging course, but it didn't really answer my questions. Or it does in later tutorials (I did the basic and dragon one, the dragon one thaught me the face rig I am using right now) but, to be honest, I am not really all that keen on watching hours of a tutorial that mostly does things I already know. And I think the only one left is the two headed ogre where he sadly didn't add proper naming to know what it will be about to the chapters.